# How to add user details to different tables immediately after user registration

Tags: plugin-development, functions, mysql

I have two wordpress database tables, to which, I want to automatically add user details after every user registration. The tables are as follows:

`mytbl_A`:

```
+--------------+--------+------------------+------------+-----------+--------+--------+
| affiliate_id | name   | email            | from_date  | thru_date | status | type   |
+--------------+--------+------------------+------------+-----------+--------+--------+
|            2 | john   | admin@example.com| 2016-10-04 | NULL      | active | NULL   |
+--------------+--------+------------------+------------+-----------+--------+--------+
```

`mytbl_A` description:

```
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| affiliate_id | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name         | varchar(100)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email        | varchar(512)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| from_date    | date                | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| thru_date    | date                | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| status       | varchar(10)         | NO   | MUL | active  |                |
| type         | varchar(10)         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and the other table `mytbl_B`

```
+--------------+---------+
| affiliate_id | user_id |
+--------------+---------+
|            2 |       2 |
+--------------+---------+
```

`mytbl_B` description:

```
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| affiliate_id | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| user_id      | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

The moment a user registers, I want to insert the user details into these two tables. I tried to use a function, but that is not working, no user details are getting added.

Function for `mytbl_A`

```
function add_to_affuser($user_id) {
global $wpdb;
$user_info = get_userdata($user_id );
$wpdb->insert( 'mytbl_A', array('mytbl_A.name' => $user_info->user_login, 'mytbl_A.email' => $user_info->user_email ), array('%s', '%s') ); 
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'add_to_affuser');
```

Function for `mytbl_B`

```
function add_to_aff($user_id) {  
global $wpdb;
$user_info = get_userdata($user_id);  
$wpdb->insert( 'mytbl_B', array('mytbl_B.user_id' => $user_info->ID ), array('%d') ); 
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'add_to_aff');
```

nothing is being added to either of the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the table names from the column names when using `$wpdb->insert()` is what worked for me:

```
function add_to_affuser($user_id) {
    global $wpdb;
    $user_info = get_userdata($user_id );
    $wpdb->insert( 'mytbl_A', array('name' => $user_info->user_login, 
              'email' => $user_info->user_email ), array('%s', '%s') ); 
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'add_to_affuser');

function add_to_aff($user_id) {  
    global $wpdb;
    $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);  
    $wpdb->insert( 'mytbl_B', array('user_id' => $user_info->ID ), array('%d') ); 
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'add_to_aff');
```

While trying to reproduce the issue reported, I noticed that tables created using `dbDelta()` (and the database description provided) had lowercase names despite trying to use `A` and `B`. I was a little unsure of how the prefixes were set up based on your code too.

Here's a demo plugin that includes the database creation part too.  Custom tables are created upon plugin activation. The custom DB tables will be updated when adding a new user.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: WPSE update custom tables when adding user
Plugin URI: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/241560
Description: 
Version: 0.0.1
Author:
Author URI:
License: GPL2/Creative Commons
*/

/**
 * Create the database tables upon activation of this plugin
 * 
 */
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'wpse241560_db_install' );
function wpse241560_db_install() {
    global $wpdb;

    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();


    $sql_affuser = "CREATE TABLE {$wpdb->prefix}affuser (
        affiliate_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
        email varchar(512) NULL,
        from_date date NULL,
        thru_date date NOT NULL,
        status varchar(10) DEFAULT 'active' NOT NULL,
        type varchar(10) NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (affiliate_id),
        KEY status (status)
    ) $charset_collate;";

    $sql_aff = "CREATE TABLE {$wpdb->prefix}aff (
        affiliate_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
        user_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (affiliate_id, user_id)
    ) $charset_collate;";

    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );

    dbDelta( $sql_affuser );
    dbDelta( $sql_aff );
}


/**
 * Update affuser table after adding a new user 
 */
add_action( 'user_register', 'wpse241560_add_to_affuser');
function wpse241560_add_to_affuser( $user_id ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $user_info = get_userdata( $user_id );

    $wpdb->insert( "{$wpdb->prefix}affuser",
                    array(
                      'name'  => $user_info->user_login,
                      'email' => $user_info->user_email
                    ),
                    array( '%s', '%s' ) ); 
}

/**
 * Update aff table after adding a new user 
 */
add_action( 'user_register', 'wpse241560_add_to_aff' );
function wpse241560_add_to_aff( $user_id ) {  
    global $wpdb;
    $user_info = get_userdata( $user_id );

    $wpdb->insert( "{$wpdb->prefix}aff",
                     array(
                        'user_id' => $user_info->ID
                     ),
                     array( '%d' ) ); 
}
```